# Book about a girl who finds out she's adopted

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for a book about a girl who plays the drums and finds out she's adopted. She sets out to find her birth mom and realizes her dad is also a musician and that she was conceived during a heatwave.

She then plays a song by *Pearl Jam* with her dad.

In the end, I'm pretty sure she goes back to her adopted parents.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please can you [edit] your post to include more detailed information, like: where and when did you read the book and in what language? when and where in the world was it set? was it a novel, novella, or short story? The [ID-request tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) has a list of questions that might help to jog your memory for more details, which would in turn help us to identify the story.

Comment: When someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 11):

I think that this is *[Where We Belong](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13067689)* by Emily Giffin, which has the birth mother as the protagonist instead of the girl.

From the summary on Goodreads:

> Marian Caldwell is a thirty-six year old television producer, living
> her dream in New York City. With a fulfilling career and satisfying
> relationship, she has convinced everyone, including herself, that her
> life is just as she wants it to be. But one night, Marian answers a
> knock on the door . . . only to find Kirby Rose, an eighteen-year-old
> girl with a key to a past that Marian thought she had sealed off
> forever. From the moment Kirby appears on her doorstep, Marian's
> perfectly constructed world—and her very identity—will be shaken to
> its core, resurrecting ghosts and memories of a passionate young love
> affair that threaten everything that has come to define her.

Her daughter Kirby, is very fond of playing the drums. When she later meets her birth father, who is also a musician, they bond by playing a song together - "Small Town" by Pearl Jam.